# Find duplicates in three fields two-by-two in MS Access

Tags: sql, duplicates, ms-access-2010

In Access 2010 I want to find duplicates from one table across 3 fields, but by pairs of fields or two by two. Basically, the duplicates either have :
- The same **last name** AND the same **date of birth**
OR
- The same **first name** AND the same **date of birth**

For example, my table is :

```
   Last name           First name          DoB

   Brook               Felicity            05/01/1970
   Carlson             Roxane              11/23/1983
   Brook               Felicity Joan       05/01/1970
   Carlson Winfield    Roxane              11/23/1983
   Ackerman            Randall             11/23/1983
```

The results of the query should find all those records except the last one (same date of birth but unique names).

What I did, using Access query wizard to find duplicates, is go step by step and create a query for each pair. However, when I create a third query to get all the results, the table takes forever to load (my table has 3000+ records). So, the first two queries don't seem to help at all.

I also created a query to concatenate the pairs of fields, thinking it would help by reducing the search in two fields instead of three, but I only get errors.
I guess I can't rely on the wizard and I have to use SQL but I'm not very comfortable with it.

How should I go about this ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic should do what you want:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t as t1 inner join
     t as t2
     on t1.dateofbirth = t2.dateofbirth and
        ( (t1.lastname = t2.lastname and t1.firstname <> t2.firstname) or
           (t1.firstname = t2.firstname and t1.lastname <> t2.lastname)
        );
```

MS Access has strange rules about what can go on an `on` clause.  You might need to write this as:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t as t1 inner join
     t as t2
     on t1.dateofbirth = t2.dateofbirth
where ( (t1.lastname = t2.lastname and t1.firstname <> t2.firstname) or
        (t1.firstname = t2.firstname and t1.lastname <> t2.lastname)
      );
```

Comment: Sorry I'm confused, is it meant to join two tables ? Because I only have one. Should I get rid of the join part ?

Comment: @Zie . . . This is meant to join only only one table to itself.  This is called a "self-join".

Comment: Ok, got it ! Learned about self join, thanks ! Access didn't like "join" so I replaced it with "inner join" and it works great !
There is just one problem: it doesn't find duplicates where first name AND last name are the same. I know I haven't mentioned this case, I'm sorry, I genuinely thought it would go without saying because as I viewed it, they couldn't be left out.
I'll try to find something by myself for now (maybe using a count >2 ?). Thanks again !

Comment: @Zie . . . I forget sometimes that MS Access requires the `inner`.

Comment: @Zie . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask.  If you have another question, you should ask it as a *question* not in a *comment*.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gordon's answer, I was able to find a solution to query all these duplicates :

- Same date of birth, same last name, same first name (didn't mention it, my bad)
- Same date of birth, same last name
- Same date of birth, same first name

I simply used my ID field so that's needed I guess.

Here it is : (to dummies like me : you need to replace "tablename" with the name of your table and use adequate field names, that's all)

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM Tablename AS t1 
INNER JOIN Tablename AS t2 
ON t1.dateofbirth  = t2.dateofbirth 
WHERE t1.ID <> t2.ID 
AND (t1.lastname = t2.lastname OR t1.firstname = t2.firstname);
```

At first I added `t1.ID <> t2.ID` inside the `ON` clause with an `AND` but Gordon is right : Access doesn't like that and makes it impossible to use Design View.

I don't know if I should have went with a GROUP BY and HAVING count instead of a self join, I guess it was a possibility, but it works as is, so...

Thank you again, Gordon !